# Why can't this script retrieve the data to another php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I made my table autoload using ajax once a user enters data in the to_date date box but it seems like I can't retrieve the data to another PHP file using this script. I'm still a beginner in coding so please be easy on me.
Please help. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // load_data(); 

        function load_data(fromdate, todate)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"vehicle_table.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{fromdate:fromdate, todate:todate},
                success:function(data) {
                    $('.activity').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
  
        let to_date = document.querySelector("#to_date");
        let from_date = document.querySelector("#from_date");
        to_date.addEventListener("change", stateHandle);
        from_date.addEventListener("change", stateHandle);
        to_date.disabled = true;
        var fromdate = $('#from_date').datepicker({  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
        var todate = $('#to_date').datepicker({  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});

        function stateHandle() {
            if(document.querySelector("#from_date").value === "") {
                to_date.disabled = true;
                $('.activity').html('');          
            } else {     
                if(document.querySelector("#to_date").value === ""){
                    to_date.disabled = false;
                    $('.activity').html('');
                } else {          
                    to_date.disabled = false;
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"vehicle_table.php",
                        method:"POST",
                        data:{fromdate:fromdate, todate:todate},
                        success:function(data) {
                            $('.activity').html(data);
                        }
                    });

            }     
            to_date.disabled = false;
            $('.activity').html('');
        } 
    } 
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $.datepicker.setDefaults({  
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'   
        });  
    });
});
</script>
```

These are my from_date and to_date.

```
<form action="vehicle_table.php" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="from_date"></label>
      <input type="date" name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form-control datepicker input" placeholder="From Date" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="to_date"></label>
      <input type="date" name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control datepicker input2" placeholder="To Date" />
    </div>                                         
    </div>
  </form>
```

I didn't see any error but it didn't get pass through the

```
if(isset($_POST['fromdate'],$_POST['todate']))
```

Comment: You have written some function in your javascript, have you called them?

Comment: ...and what debugging have you done? Check the content of the outgoing AJAX request in your browser's Network tool first of all, to see if it contains what you expect in terms of parameters and their values. Then in the PHP log the contents of `$_POST` when the request arrives.

Comment: when you say `I can't retrieve the data to another PHP file using this script` you mean the script was working fine before, when pointing to a different php page?

Comment: Could you please paste the contents of you `vehicle_table.php` file. This will help us see what data you are getting back from the 'POST' request. You can also check the response using chrome dev tools network tab, just filter by XHR.

Comment: I used all the functions inside the javascript. And the if(isset($_POST['fromdate'],$_POST['todate'])) I used is on the vehicle_table.php

Comment: The problem is that once I execute the ajax to try and load the table is that, the functions cant get past through the if statement.

Comment: I am exploring this option as I think it would be pretty nice if I make it work.

Comment: `can't get past`... that's too vague. You need to find out some information which gives a clue about _why_ you can't. At the moment we don't know anything relevant to that. Read my [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71940357/why-cant-this-script-retrieve-the-data-to-another-php-file?noredirect=1#comment127121494_71940357) and check the things I asked you to check. If you can't get past that point then it's probably because the variables aren't being sent as you expect. You need to check what _is_ being sent/received so you can start to work out where it goes wrong.